# Armazenar itens em um carrinho

Tags: java

Boa tarde!

Galera, tenho um problema em meu código onde tenho um método para abrir o catálogo (abrircatalogo) com alguns itens e selecionar os iens que eu desejo, mas não consigo passar esses itens selecionados para um outro método onde eu so visualizarei o carrinho (método carrinho) no qual eu selecionei meus itens.

Preciso so visualizá-los e ter opções para voltar e continuar selecionando ou finalizar a compra dos pedidos

Poderiam me ajudar?

```
package javaapplication6;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class JavaApplication6 {

    public static int[] codigo;
    public static String[] nome;
    public static double[] preco;
    public static String[] descricao;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Muito obrigado pelo Acesso! O que deseja fazer primeiro?");
            System.out.println("\n===========================");
            System.out.println("|     1 - Catálogo        |");
            System.out.println("|     2 - Carrinho        |");
            System.out.println("|     3 - Finalizar       |");
            System.out.println("|     4 - Voltar          |");
            System.out.println("|     0 - Sair            |");
            System.out.println("===========================\n");

            int opcao = in.nextInt();
                switch (opcao){
                    case 1:
                    carregarcatalogo();
                    break;

                    case 2:
                    carrinho();    
                    case 3: 
                    finalizarcompra();
                }

    }

public static void carregarcatalogo() throws IOException{
      Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

        DataInputStream br = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("produto.db"));

            int tamanho = br.readInt();
            codigo = new int[tamanho];
            nome = new String[tamanho];
            preco = new double[tamanho];
            descricao = new String[tamanho];

            for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
            codigo[i] = br.readInt();
            nome[i] = br.readUTF();
            preco[i] = br.readDouble();
            descricao[i] = br.readUTF();
    }
            abrircatalogo(tamanho, codigo, nome, preco, descricao);
}

public static void abrircatalogo(int tamanho ,int[] codigo, String[] nome, double[] preco, String[] descricao){
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

                System.out.printf("+-----+------+------+------+---|\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
                System.out.printf("| %06d | %-15s | R$%7.2f | %-35s |\n",
                    codigo[i], nome[i], preco[i], descricao[i]);
                System.out.printf("+-----+------+------+------+---|\n");
            }

            System.out.println("\n===========================");
            System.out.println("Digite 1 para selecionar itens");
            System.out.println("Digite 2 para ver o carrinho");
            System.out.println("Digite 3 para sair");
            System.out.println("===========================\n");

            int opcao = in.nextInt();
            switch(opcao){
                case 1:

            System.out.println("Selecione itens ou pressione 2 para ir ao carrinho:");        

            int user = in.nextInt();
            int quantidade = 3;
            int cod [] = new int[quantidade];

            for (int i = 0; i < cod.length; i++) {
                 cod[i] = in.nextInt();
                 carrinho(cod);
                if(cod[i] == 2 ){
                    carrinho(cod);
                    break;
                }else{

                }
                System.out.println("#" + (i+1) + "ª selecionado e enviado ao carrinho");
            }  
                case 3:
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            }
    }

    public static void carrinho(int cod[]){
        for (int i = 0; i < cod.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("cod");
        }
    }

    public static void finalizarcompra(){

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Para finalizar sua compra, preencha os dados");

        System.out.print("Nome completo que está no Cartão de Crédito: ");
        String cliente = in.next();
        System.out.print("Numero do Cartão de Crédito: ");
        int numCredito = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Data de vencimento: ");
        int vencimento = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("CVV: ");
        int cvv = in.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite, Arthur

Não realizei nenhum teste ainda mas, apenas lendo o código pode testar por gentileza?

```
int opcao = in.nextInt();
                switch (opcao){
                    case 1:
                    carregarcatalogo();
                    break;

                    case 2:
                    carrinho();
                    break;

                    case 3: 
                    finalizarcompra();
                    break;

                   default:
                   System.out.println("Opção invalida");


                }
```

Answer (score 0):

O método carrinho espera um argumento, um vetor de inteiros.

```
 switch (opcao){
                case 1:
                carregarcatalogo();
                break;

                case 2:
                carrinho(codigo);    
                case 3: 
                finalizarcompra();
            }
```

Lembrando que o vetor deve ser inicializado antes se não você terá problema de NullPointerException dentro do método carrinho().